# C++ Problem filling structs with values from another struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm having an issue trying to figure out why I am not getting the correct functionality with a piece of code. I have looked around to try and find a solution however, I haven't been able to do so. Below is an example of my code:

```
//Structs
typedef struct
{
    int gene[60];
    int fitness;

} individual;

typedef struct
{
    int cond[5];
    int out;
}rule;

//Array of individuals
individual population[P]

int function(individual solution){
    int k = 0;
    //Array of rules
    rule rulebase[10]
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
            rulebase[i].cond[j] = solution.gene[k++];
        }
        rulebase[i].out = solution.gene[k++];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        cout << rulebase[0].cond[i];
    }
```

The solution that is passed into the function is the first individual in 'population' and the gene array contains only binary numbers, for example:

```
gene = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1] //There will be 60 in total
```

The desired functionality is to fill the rule structures in the rulebase with the values found in the solution. For example, using the example above the first rule in the rulebase will have the values below in the 'cond' array:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

and the 'out' will be the next integer in the solution:

```
[1]
```

Then the next rule will be filled with the next values in the solution the same way.

The problem that I am having is the code seems to be filling the 'cond' array of each rule with all of the values in the solution, as oppose to the desired way described above. For example, when I print the genes in 'rulebase[0]' I get:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```

As oppose to:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1]
```

I can't seem to figure out why I am getting this problem as the code looks to me like it should work? Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am seriously struggling!

Comment: Unrelated: C++ learned a lot from twenty-some years of C and allows you to write `typedef struct { ... }rule;` as `struct rule{ ... };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rule contains only 5 values in `cond`, not 10 as you show. Its just your code that prints the values of `rulebase[0]` that is wrong, i.e. it exceeds array bounds and prints - in addition to the `cond`-values of `rulebase[0]` - the values of `out` and `cond` of the next rule, which - in memory - come next.